# How to set up Azure Pipeline for Angular App

Tags: angular, azure, azure-devops, angular-ui-router, azure-pipelines

I am struggling to get the `Azure Pipeline` working properly.
I performed steps as shown in the following figure. As one can see all the steps and build are successful, the build was also able to transfer **`web.config`** file into **`dist/app/`** directory on the azure server. Upon performing following steps when I tried to open the app page it took me to `microsoft azure portal URL` which was generated while creating the app resources on Azure. I am not able to grasp where am I going wrong here and why I can not see the Angular App Page?

**Note:** *The app works perfectly on localhost*

[image: Azure steps]
[image: App Deployment]

Comment: Not sure what is wrong, but maybe this would help https://johnpapa.net/deploy-angular-to-azure-vsts-angular-cli/

Comment: I already tried it ... but did not work. One query though, Do I need to set-up release as well, since I am already deploying the app through pipeline ?

Comment: it's a different approach. by setting releases you'll be able to deploy the same artifact to multiple environments

Comment: @Sopan Kurkute Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT not yet resolved. I'm not sure what am I doing wrong here. I am still digging into it.

Answer (score 1):

To troubleshoot,

Can you navigate to the Kudu console and see if the actual files have been deployed? I would recommend you to delete the **`hostingstart.html`**

Also you need to add a custom [`web.config`](https://slides.com/sajeetharan/angular-continuous-integration#/11) to avoid the 404 errors.

I have [step by step slides](https://slides.com/sajeetharan/angular-continuous-integration#/11) to deploy the app to Azure.

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether the files are deployed to Azure web service through [Azure kudu](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/11/08/how-to-access-kudu-scm-for-an-azure-app-service-environment-ase/). Here is an [example](https://medium.com/better-programming/deploy-angular-app-using-azure-devops-build-and-release-pipelines-f7f77ca28be4) on how to deploy angular app to azure web app.

[image]

[image]